# De-normalise/Transpose spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Give the following dataframe, How can the data in rows be converted to columns. 
The list of property name is not defined. ie, there can be more properties than which are defined here. I am looking for a code sample in scala using in apache spark

```
UserCode    | PropertyName          | PropertyValue 
1           | First Name            | Ram
1           | Last Name             | Shri 
1           | Address               | Ayodhya 
2           | First Name            | Laxman 
2           | Lastname              | Shri 
2           | Address               | Ayodhya
2           | Skill                 | Archery 
2           | Mariatal Status       | Married 
2           | Age                   | 23 
3           | First Name            | Sita 
3           | Last Name             | Devi
3           | Address               | Ayodhya
```

Expected output

```
UserCode    | First Name            | Last Name | Address | Skill   | Age
1           | Ram                   | Shri      | Ayodhya |         |       
2           | Laxman                | Shri      | Ayodhya | Archery | 23
3           | Sita                  | Devi      | Ayodhya |         |
```

Comment: I have studied the question "Transpose Dataframe using Spark Scala without using Pivot function" I am looking for a sample code

Comment: I'm not sure that I actually understand your last comment.

Comment: I am referring to a a question on SO "Transpose Dataframe using Spark Scala without using Pivot function"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're okay using pivot, this is quite straightforward.

```
val df = Seq(
(1, "First Name", "Ram"),
(1, "Last Name", "Shri"),
(1, "Address", "Ayodhya"),
(2, "First Name", "Laxman"),
(2, "Last Name", "Shri"),
(2, "Address", "Ayodhya"),
(2, "Skill", "Archery"),
(2, "Marital Status", "Married"),
(2, "Age", "23"),
(3, "First Name", "Sita"),
(3, "Last Name", "Devi"),
(3, "Address", "Ayodhya")
).toDF("userCode", "propertyName", "propertyValue")

df.groupBy("userCode").pivot("propertyName").agg(first("propertyValue")).show

+--------+-------+----+----------+---------+--------------+-------+
|userCode|Address| Age|First Name|Last Name|Marital Status|  Skill|
+--------+-------+----+----------+---------+--------------+-------+
|       1|Ayodhya|null|       Ram|     Shri|          null|   null|
|       2|Ayodhya|  23|    Laxman|     Shri|       Married|Archery|
|       3|Ayodhya|null|      Sita|     Devi|          null|   null|
+--------+-------+----+----------+---------+--------------+-------+
```